# iOS ViewControllers Flow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Now, I have a table view called Products with a add button on the navigation bar. When click on add button, the new view controller will be pushed to show which called AddItem. Here is the thing, Can I open a new view controllers A from AddItem and reopen Products from A?

May be my description a little bit confused.
ProductsTableViewController --(Push)--> AddItemViewController --(Modal/Push)--> AViewController --(Modal)--> ProductsTableViewController(Should be exact same as the first one)

And there may be some controllers between AddItemViewController and AViewController.

I have two solution:
1. When open ProductsTableViewController from A, get the same instance as before
2. Create a new instance of ProductsTableViewController and get data from an singleton class.

My concern is that is there any memory leak or protential risk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your best bet is to use delegates. not sure why you want to do this, but if you have all your vcs in the stack, and your "ProductsTableViewController" is the root, then just have it move to the top of the stack.

Comment: The purpose is add a item to table view. But while adding, I need more than 1 VCs. How to move it to the top of the stack? @DoS

Comment: why do you need more than one vc? a vc is typically meant to handle all the current views. my next question would be whats on that first vc that you need it presented again for the last vc to function? if everything is in the same navigation stack you can call [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES] and that will bring you back to the root vc.